# Fix CORS header Access-Control-Allow-Origin missing on plugin development on eclipse

Tags: server, eclipse-plugin, jetty, jax-rs

-I am try to make a modular application using eclipse plugin development and  using jax-rs.
 -I want to access an event source created by jetty server and translate each event in time. 

-When i try to access the event i am get this error in firefox that run my client html 5 page : 
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:9050/services/events. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

-I know that i must configure the server , but i don't have .htaccess and no web-inf dir.

 -Is there any to declare this file in the vm arguments using eclipse ? 
 -Is there any other way to do it ? 

-I don't have WEB-INF directory and i don't know if it supported in this plugin development approach. 

 -I don't have main function I have only bundles (activator, ect.) and I don't have main function . 

-I also have manifest.mf file

Any help is accepted.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try implementing a response filter which would add your needed headers to the response.

```
@Provider
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
        // the wildcard char `*` will allow any origin
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        // add anything and everything you need
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
        // etc
    }
}
```

Don't forget to register it.